# Hadoop and Geoserver

Tags: hadoop, hbase, datastore, geoserver, geotools

I'am intending to develop a new datastore based on Hadoop/HBase for Geotools to use it in Geoserver just to visualise Raster data (tiled satellite image).  Has anyone done something similar or even know if this is possible ?
I already know how to compile and integrate the opensource datastores like the CSV one, but I have no idea of how I can start implementing this datastore on Hadoop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [GeoWave](https://ngageoint.github.io/geowave/) project which seems to be exactly what you are looking for. However it currently supports Accumulo fully and we are working on adding HBase support for the same.